# Unable to configure saving and loading with firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I followed all steps such as adding the database SDK to Unity etc., but when I try to connect Unity to Firebase, I'm getting an error.

> Assets\Script\RealTimeLoading.cs(14,21): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference' to 'DatabaseReference'

I followed a lot of tutorials, they are never getting errors, just me. Here is my code

```
 using Firebase;
 using Firebase.Database;
 using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class RealTimeLoading : MonoBehaviour
 {
     DatabaseReference reference;
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        
 
 
     }
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         
     }
 }
```

The error is on this line:

```
 FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: your code seems to be fine according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data)

Comment: Did you try full-qualifying `DatabaseReference` on your `reference` field?

Comment: What is `Firebase.Unity.Editor` btw? Are you sure this should be in your runtime script? And usually if you have a good IDE you simply hover on a type and see the full type name ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After briefly going through your `using` statements, I don't believe that there should be a `DatabaseReference` other than the one in `Firebase.Database`. That makes me think that you have another `class` in your project's root namespace with the same name.

First, I'd recommend removing `Firebase.Unity.Editor` and definitely let me know if there's still some documentation recommending it.

Then you should be able to simply write:

```
using DatabaseReference = Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference;
```

with your other `using` directives. So the top of your file may look like:

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using DatabaseReference = Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference;
```

Be careful with this because if there is another class named `DatabaseReference` in your code base, you may run into this naming conflict more often. It could be beneficial to either move it to its own namespace or to rename it if possible. But this should get you unstuck immediately.

*Alternatively*: instead of adding the `using` alias, you may instead fully qualify the name in your class. For example:

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class RealTimeLoading : MonoBehaviour
{
    Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference reference;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }
}
```

I would recommend against doing both of these in one file, but you may have to use each under different circumstances.